# Using regular expression to find the value after the period in a url

Tags: regex, preg-match

I am looking to extract the number situated after the period of the 'specid' and just before the '&type' part of the following url:

"**http://subdom.someurl.com/cat/motorparts?id=12345&specid=245038.100006592&type=10&page=0**"

The digits are variables so they may fluctuate in length.

I am a newbie when it comes to regular expression but any help to get me going on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not big on PHP, but it should look something like this:

```
preg_match('/specid=\d+\.(\d+)/i', $input, $matches);
```

`$matches` is an array storing all the matches. The value you're after will be in the second element. See [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for more.

I'm not 100% sure, but from what I can infer, make sure you use single-quotes around the pattern string, otherwise you will have to escape the backslashes, which makes regexes looke ven more unintelligible than they already are.

Comment: Fantastic! It worked like a charm. Thanks for all your help Joe. Here is how I used it: if(preg_match('/specid=\d+\.(\d+)/i', $input, $matches))
 {$theNumber = $matches[1];}

Answer (score 2):

@Quick Joe Smith's regex answer would do fine.

You can also use parsing of url components in PHP to retreive your data, then use simple
string operations

http://codepad.org/9kjggw8U

```
<?php
$tokens = array();
parse_str("http://subdom.someurl.com/cat/motorparts?id=12345&specid=245038.100006592&type=10&page=0",$tokens);
var_dump($tokens['specid']);
?>
```

Comment: 95% of the way there. The OP only wanted a portion of the `specid` parameter, so at the very least a substring would be required. Otherwise, a more robust solution than a regex-based one.